# how to send form values every second and save it to a variable each time php

Tags: php, forms

i am working on online exam system witch is time based system and it has a start time and end time i have to save the value of the answer sheet (witch is a form containing radio button) into a database i want  to save the value of the whole form in the data type like this `1,2,3,1,1,0,0,2` i need to get data of a form every second (because if the student close the browser then i have saved the answer text file in my data base)
i am wondering how can i do this without submit the form after each answer
thank you.

Comment: hint: xmlhttprequest/ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to periodically -- or better, when the user makes a change to the form -- send the answers back to the server.

There are many libraries, such as jQuery, that make Ajax programming easier to implement.